# Imprimir outra página com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um sistema do qual mostra o resultado de uma consulta. Nessa página tem o botão imprimir, porém preciso fazer com que ao clicar no botão imprimir, imprima uma outra página formatada sem ter que abrí-la para isso, ou se for o caso, fazer que nem acontece com download, abrir e fechar automaticamente. Tenho o seguinte código na página principal ( index.php ):

```
    <script>
               $(function(){ 
                   //evnto que deve carregar a janela a ser impressa 
                   $('#imprimir').click(function(){ 
                      newWindow = window.open('imprimir.php'); 
                       //imprime e fecha a nova janela quando estiver carregada 
                       $(newWindow).ready(function() { 
                           newWindow.print(); 
                           newWindow.close(); 
                       }); 
                   }); 
               }); 
            </script>
<a href="#" style="color: #666666; font-weight: bold" id="imprimir"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir Orçamento</a>
```

Comment: no lugar de usar o `window.open` você poderia usar um iframe para o trabalho.

Comment: Desculpe TobyMosque, não entendi

Comment: Você quer que imprima automaticamente?

Comment: Sim. Depois de clicar no botão imprimir, ele ler a página que vai ser impressa e logo em seguida fechar a página. Tipo o que ocorre em download de arquivos, onde abre, manda o arquivo e a página fecha automaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

olha, neste caso é melhor você criar um iFrame para o conteúdo desejado, até pq o `window.open` pode vir a ser bloqueado pelo Browser.

```
var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
iFrame.addEventListener("load", function () { 
  iFrame.contentWindow.focus();
  iFrame.contentWindow.print();
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.removeChild(iFrame);
  }, 0);
});        
iFrame.style.display = "none";
iFrame.src = "imprimir.php";
document.body.appendChild(iFrame);
```

abaixo segue um exemplo funcional com um trecho de HTML qual quer inserido pelo usuário.

```js
var taRawHtml = document.getElementById("taRawHtml");
var btImprimir = document.getElementById("btImprimir");

btImprimir.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var html = taRawHtml.value.trim();
  if (html) {       
    var blob = new Blob([html], { type: "text/html" });        
    var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    iFrame.addEventListener("load", function () { 

      iFrame.contentWindow.focus();
      iFrame.contentWindow.print();
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(iFrame);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(iFrame.src);
      }, 0);
    });        
    iFrame.style.display = "none";
    iFrame.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.body.appendChild(iFrame);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body, div, input, textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;    
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}
```

```html
Insira um trecho de HTML dentro do input abaixo:
<textarea id="taRawHtml">
  <h1>Hello Wolrd</h1>
</textarea>
<input id="btImprimir" type="button" value="Imprimir" />
```

Infelizmente o exemplo acima não vai executar aqui no SO, devido a uma politica aplicada ao iFrame do Snippet, mas você pode ver ele em ação no seguinte <kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/r8pauj6t/)</kbd>